# AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter infinite loop

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I am in the process of using a custom single sign on mechanism. As a first phase I am trying to login every user using a test account using the following code. However I get stuck in an infinite loop of authentication. This doesn't make any sense to me.

TasFilterA .java

```
public class TasFilterA extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {


    protected TasFilterA(RequestMatcher requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher) { 

        super(requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher);            

    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {



        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null) {             

            return auth;

        }
        else {              


            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            SimpleGrantedAuthority us = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("tas.babson.edu");
            authorities.add(us);                

            Authentication token  = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("tonyo", "pw", authorities);            


            return token;

        }           

    }

}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {   

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    

            http.authorizeRequests()            
                .antMatchers("/login**", "/error").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .authenticated()                
                .and()              
                .addFilterAfter(getTASAuthenticationFilter(                                 
                        new AndRequestMatcher(
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**")//                          
                                )
                        ), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);                    

    }  

    TasFilterA getTASAuthenticationFilter( RequestMatcher requestMatcher ) {

        TasFilterA filter = new TasFilterA( requestMatcher );           
         return filter;
 }


}
```

Any light someone could shed on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to this? I have the same problem.